# PHP variable defined in 'parent' file not recognized in 'required' file

Tags: php

I am trying to access a variable defined in parent file from inside the required file, like this:

<<< parent.php >>>

```
$controller = 'index';
require ('child.php');
```

<<< child.php >>>

```
echo $controller;
```

---

somehow, I am receiving a null output, which means that the variable is not accessible via child.php..
am I doing something wrong here?
if possible, please let me know how I can call the above variable in my child.php file, if above seems to be wrong.

Regards
Nikhil Gupta

Comment: It should work this way. Are you 100% sure `child.php` gets included?

Comment: Try printing "test" as a constant to ensure the file is included as Pekka said...

Comment: @Pekka: yeah, child.php gets included. other functions inside the child.php are getting run easily.
@cinqo: yeah file is being included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your variable declared outside a function body? If not, it needs to be.

Also, when calling the variable from your child file, try "initializing" it with the Global keyword before using it...

like

```
Global $myParentVariable;
```

...then try printing it. Also, for debugging purposes, set the variable to a constant in your parent file instead of deriving the value in some function. In other words, make sure it's not a function turning the value to null. (I see you are doing that in the post - but not sure if you modified it for simplicity)

Comment: well yeah.. in the child.php, I am trying to pass this $controller variable inside a function (as parameter), but that should not affect this right? I also tried to dump the variable via a print (and var_dump) statement and both gave me null output. The strangest thing is that this works on my localhost but my server doesnt like it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, Got the issue here.
It was a mistake of mine, I guess.
The error was not in the above lines, but somehow another variable was rather than accessing the parent php, was accessing the child php directly.

So, guess, it works out now, why the variables were not available.

Answer (score 0):

That is strange. Try to see if variable is part of defined variables:

```
$vars = get_defined_vars();
print_r($vars);
```

Also, If your variable exists in a function, you can globalize it with `global` keyword.

Comment: Yeah, I am not accessing the variable inside the function, just trying to pass it as a parameter for the function. :|