# Variable scope in a required file

Tags: php, scope

I'm calling a file named ajax.php (from my browser for testing)

ajax.php require_once delete.php

delete.php require_once no_direct.php

delete.php starts like this:

```
$allowed = array('group'=>'admin');
require_once(ASSETS.'/no_direct.php'); //Yes, ASSETS is defined and no_direct is being included.
```

In no_direct.php I'm trying to:

```
var_dump($allowed)
```

and I just keep coming up NULL.

Does this happen because we are running inside ajax.php's require_once function and the scope of $allowed pushes back to the GLOBAL scope not allowing me to access it from no_delete.php?

I was looking here: [PHP variable defined in 'parent' file not recognized in 'required' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954049/php-variable-defined-in-parent-file-not-recognized-in-required-file) , just to be diligent.

I'm sure I could solve this with the GLOBAL keyword, but I was hoping for a little clarification.  The PHP scope doc didn't seem to answer the question for me.

It wasn't wrapped in another function as thought to be the case.

Comment: You are not inside a function somewhere? Is `ASSETS` a file path?

Comment: Yes, ASSETS is a FILE PATH.  So it will end up being something like C:/apache/htdocs/

Comment: have you any other code in no_direct.php ?

Comment: @Pekka, no, I'm not in a function...other than require_once ;)  ajax.php has a direct call to require_once same with delete.php.  In terms of what I would believe to be the processing order of the files, the lines in my question should be accurate.

Comment: why don't you check **actual** ASSETS value?

Comment: @Tufan, yes, there is other code in no_direct.php, but my var_dump is the first line after a comment.  I delete all other code out of no_direct.php and tried just with the var_dump.  Still the same thing.  Also emptied my browser cache just in case ;)  Nothing is cached on the site though.

Comment: @Senica you are also not in a function that wraps the main body of ajax.php? Just checking to make 100% sure, because this is the most frequent reason for this.

Comment: @Col.  I have checked ASSETS value.  I'm certain it's correct.  If it wasn't it my no_delete.php file wouldn't be echoing a NULL value either.

Comment: why not. it is perfectly possible. So, what does ASSETS contain?

Comment: @Pekka, made me comment out two other required file in my ajax.php file.  One of them is causing an issue.  Thanks.

Comment: all i can think of is that you missed the varibale name at no_direct.php - but i think it's not the case, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any chance that you already have called `require_once(ASSETS.'/no_direct.php');` before you assigned value to `$allowed`?

```
require_once(ASSETS.'/no_direct.php');
...

$allowed = array('group'=>'admin');
require_once(ASSETS.'/no_direct.php');
```

Script `no_direct.php` should not output `$allowed` in this case.

Output will be:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: allowed in D:\wampserver\www\gim\no_direct.php on line 2
NULL
```

*p.s. there's my path on localhost in wamp for my test file*

Comment: That is definitely it.  I just posted right after you said that, saying I had found the same thing.  Sorry guys.  Hopefully it helps someone else out though.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this happen because we are running inside ajax.php's require_once function and the scope of $allowed pushes back to the GLOBAL scope not allowing me to access it from no_delete.php?

**Definitely not.**

There are NO scope issues regarding includes.
The only scope-dependent issue is **user-defined functions**.

So, if there are no functions involved, the only cause can be some mistake/mistype - you're editing/including wrong file, or including HTML code it via http or something of the kind. Just double-check.

Answer (score 0):

So my ajax.php file also require_once build.php and config.php

My build.php file require_once no_direct.php as well.

As the function suggests, it will only require no_direct.php ONCE!

So the NULL that I was seeing was coming from build.php's include and not the delete.php's include of no_delete.