# Method in "parent" file available in "required" file?

Tags: php, require

If I have two classes in two files, A.php and B.php, if A.php contains require_once(B.php) and A.php also contains the static method do_thing(), will A::do_thing() be available in B.php, assuming the starting point is always A.php and B.php is always require_once'd in A.php? I can't seem to find any related questions except for [this one regarding variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954049/php-variable-defined-in-parent-file-not-recognized-in-required-file), but it was not obvious if this applied to methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer appears to be yes. Assuming:

**A.php**

```
<?php
require_once('B.php');
class A{
    public static function do_thing(){
        echo "Things done!\n";
    }
}
```

**B.php**

```
<?php
class B{
    public function git_er_done(){
        A::do_thing();
    }
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?
require_once('A.php');
$b = new B();
$b->git_er_done();
```

To be thorough, you should also `require_once('A.php');` in your **B.php** because that is where the dependency is, and given your desire to avoid `auto_loading` it is wise to avoid the perils of assuming the loading is taking place somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, if I had the choice I'd use autoload, but unfortunately I'm working on a legacy (read: PHP4) codebase that doesn't/can't use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, A::do_thing() will be available in B.php. For example, in the following, we include B.php which calls A() function before it is declared and it works. PHP parses before executing :

A.php :

```
<?php
include('B.php');
function A() {
    echo 'A';
}
```

B.php :

```
<?php
A();
```

Calling A.php script will output :

> A